# Dimension of global sections with vanishing ideal sheaf conditions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces

We blow up $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ at $r$ points $P_{1},\ldots,P_{r}$
$$\pi: \tilde{X} \to \mathbb{P}^{n}$$
with exceptional divisors $E_{1},\ldots,E_{r}$. Let $H$ be a hyperplane of $\mathbb{P}^{n}$, let $\displaystyle D=k\pi^{*}H-\sum_{i}E_{i}$, where $k$ is chosen large enough to make $D$ ample. Now I want to compute $h^{0}(\tilde{X},\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(ND))$ for some integer $N$.

A fact we can use is that: let $\mathcal{I}_{i}$ be the ideal sheaf $\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(E_{i})$, then there is an isomorphism
$$H^{0}(\tilde{X},\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(Nk\pi^{*}H-N\sum E_{i})) \simeq H^{0}(\mathbb{P}^{n},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}(NkH)\otimes \prod \mathcal{I}_{i}^{N}).$$

The base case ($r=1$) seems to be easy. We can assume $P_{1}=O=[1:0:\cdots:0]$ and view it as a linear subspace of codimension $n$ by $x_{1}=\cdots=x_{n}=0$. Then I can compute the number of generators of global sections:
$$\{x_{0}^{i_{0}}\cdots x_{n}^{i_{n}}:i_{0}+\cdots+i_{n}=Nk\ \text{ and } i_{1}+\cdots+i_{n} \geq N\},$$
it would give me the generators with vanishing multiplicity at least $N$ at $P_{1}$.

Further, I think for all $r\leq n+1$ would be similar, basically
$$\{x_{0}^{i_{0}}\cdots x_{n}^{i_{n}}:i_{0}+\cdots+i_{n}=Nk \text{ and } r \text{ conditions } i_{0}+\cdots+\hat{i_{j}}+\cdots+i_{n} \geq N\}.$$

The question is when $r > n+1$, how do I write vanishing conditions to count generators?

Comment: I don't know that this is something so easily done, precisely because shifting your points into standard positions by a change of coordinates becomes less helpful. If I remember correctly, on a philosophical level this somehow has to do with the variety no longer being toric after so many blowups.

Comment: I agree after so many blowups, toric invariant points would be exhausted. But how that not being toric will affect this calculation of $H^{0}$?

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that there is something fundamentally combinatorial about the formulas you have already, and secretly that is tied into the varieties at hand being toric, so you should not necessarily expect something so clean once $r > n+1$. I'm struggling to remember anything else; it's been four or five years since I thought about a more annoying version of this problem while in grad school. It was a somewhat frustrating realization that "this thing would be toric hence trivial if I had just one point fewer, arg!", but I'm afraid I don't have much additional insight.